# Proper use of ON CASCADE UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

While trying to run the following query:

```
UPDATE Flight
SET FLNO = '1001'
WHERE FLNO = '1000';
```

I receive the following error:

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`user/FlightLegInstance`, CONSTRAINT `FlightLegInstance_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`FLNO`) REFERENCES `FlightLeg` (`FLNO`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

The following are my creation queries:

Flight:

```
CREATE TABLE Flight (
FLNO INTEGER NOT NULL,
Meal varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Smoking char(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (FLNO)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

FlightLeg:

```
CREATE TABLE FlightLeg (
FLNO INTEGER NOT NULL,
Seq char(25) NOT NULL,
FromA char(3) NOT NULL,
ToA char(3) NOT NULL,
DeptTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
ArrTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
Plane INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (FLNO, Seq),
FOREIGN KEY (FLNO) REFERENCES Flight(FLNO) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (FromA) REFERENCES Airport(Code),
FOREIGN KEY (ToA) REFERENCES Airport(Code)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

FlightLegInstance:

```
CREATE TABLE FlightLegInstance (
Seq char(25) NOT NULL,
FLNO INTEGER NOT NULL,
FDate DATE NOT NULL,
ActDept DATETIME NOT NULL,
ActArr DATETIME NOT NULL,
Pilot INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Seq, FLNO, FDate),
FOREIGN KEY (FLNO) REFERENCES FlightLeg(FLNO) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (FLNO, FDate) REFERENCES FlightInstance(FLNO, FDate) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I would assume that the error is in one of the two FK definitions of FlightLegInstance, but I'm not sure. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please use SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Eg give FlightInstance DDL, input, output and desired output. Also, the (FLNO) to Flight is redundant if have a FlightLegInstance (FLNO, ...) FK to FlightInstance & (as you presumably do) a FlightInstance FK (FLNO) to Flight. Shouldn't FlightLegInstance have FK (FLNO, Seq) to FlightLeg? PS [Between two tables, do not define several ON UPDATE CASCADE clauses that act on the same column in the parent table or in the child table.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Answer (score 0):

this is not working just because you have defind [flno] column in second table as foriegn key 
the solution of this problem is you have to update it at both places
thanks